# Laravel view share doesnt work in modularing system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

simply i can use modular system in laravel, but i cant use view share in this solution,

**app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php**

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('name', 'MY NAME');
    }
}
```

**app/Modules/NewCurrency/Controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('layouts.admin.new_user.index');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/layouts/admin.new_user.index.blade.php**

```
{{ $name }}
```

I get this Error:

```
Undefined variable: name
```

Comment: can you try to dd('test') from the Controller class and check that its called

Comment: @AmirBar yes, i dont have any problem for display view, but some variables such as `Auth` , `$name` doesnt work

Comment: I want to make sure that the constructer in the abstract class is being called, if you put dd('test') inside it, you see the test message when you run the app?

Comment: @AmirBar yes, i dont have eny problem and i can see that

Comment: try change "class IndexControllerextends Controller"
 to "class IndexControllerextends extends Controller"

Comment: @AmirBar `IndexControllerextends` is only wrong pasted into topic

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it working, so the problem is in somewhere else that you dont show us

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111976/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-amir-bar).

Comment: @AmirBar can you continue this discussion in chat ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this

```
View::share()
```

Because the method that you wrote is used by other way. You should  place calls to share within a service provider's boot method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends   ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('key', 'value');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.let me to check that